# Java. array[double variable]

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a program like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
double n = sc.nextDouble();
double[]d = new double[n];
```

I am not able to execute this as I get this error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int`

I know I could cast it to int as `(int)`, but the problem is that n can be a very big number (up to 10^6)

How can I make an array like this:

```
new array[variable which can be big (up to 10^6)]
```

Comment: 10⁶ is not a big number, and you can't have an array that has decimal amount of elements. How many numbers would you store in an `double[1.5]`? Use ints to create arrays.

Comment: Why are you asking for a `double` in the first place? Why not just use an `int`? It doesn't make sense for an array to have 10.5 elements...

Comment: An `int` variable can store up to 2^31 positive values (~2 billion). Array of doubles with 2 billion elements will occupy 16 GB of RAM. Is it enough for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this :

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

Actually `int` is big enough to hold 10^6:

```
int:   32 bit              Min = -2 147 483 648                  Max = +2 147 483 647
```

Comment: Oh.. I was wrong, probably because my program didnt work for numbers bigger than 1042..Okay, thanks, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

Java's max value of int variable is `2147483647 (2^31-1)`. Anyway, it's bigger than 10^6, and I don't believe you need an array with more than 2147483647 values in it (and you can't).

Also, as others mentiond, it doesn't make sense to have an array with e.g. 10.5 values. Int type should always be used for this.

So just scan an integer:

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

in Java, array length data type has to be an int.
Anyway, for value up to 10^6 `int` is big enough.
So you can decide to use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double[] d = new double[n];
    }
}
```

Max limit value for an int in Java is 2147483647.